# What's the best way to convert constraints into joints?

Tags: algorithm, constraints

I just wondered what approaches are suitable to convert constraints into joints.
Let's say I've got a congruency constraint of two body axes and an offset constraint of two body planes. If the plane surface normals are equivalent to the axes, these two constraints describe a revolute joint.

But how can I compute this via algorithms? What is the best way?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Although I get a rough idea of what you would linke to achieve, could you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Ok i'll try: There are two bodies. I have got a constraint for a congruency of two lines. Each line belongs to a body. So these two lines can not move relatively perpendicular to the lines. They can only rotate (around the lines direction) and move along their direction. The second constraint defines an offset or congruency between two planes. Each plane is perpendicular to the bodys line. If i say the two planes shall be congruent the movement of these two bodies relatively is only possible in one DOF. Rotation around the lines... This equals a revolute joint....